# Input form to add an element in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, flow, powerapps-forms, input

My goal is to create an input form, where users can enter some values for some fields in order to update a list with the new elements inserted. The list on SharePoint is just existing. I have to "develop" the remaining structures and link them.
I am almost new to SharePoint, therefore firstly I need to define the macro-dev-steps, such as for example:

- create an app with PowerApps
- create link between the app and the list through a flow
- ...

Then I will be able to do my own reasearch for details (and maybe add some question on the forum, too).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SharePoint Online?

It is supported to have Power Apps connected to SharePoint Online directly, with or without Power Automate (Flow).

You can see the links below for a tutorial series on using Power Apps, Power Automate, and Power BI with SharePoint Online.

[Integrate Power Apps, Power Automate, and Power BI with SharePoint Online.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-scenario-intro)

[Set up lists for SharePoint Online integration with Power Apps, Power Automate, and Power BI.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-scenario-setup)